# Convert multiple binary columns into crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, crosstab

I am trying to convert the following dataset which has multiple binary variables into a crosstab.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colour_blue': [1, 0, 1], 'colour_green': [0, 1, 1],
                   'colour_red': [1, 1, 0], 'emotion_happy': [1, 1, 1],'emotion_angry': [0, 1, 1], 'emotion_sad': [0, 0, 1]})
```

into the following crosstab but i am having no luck

| emotion | blue | green | red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| happy | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| angry | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| sad | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is matix multiplication:

```
df.filter(like='emotion').T @ df.filter(like='colour')
```

Output:

```
               colour_blue  colour_green  colour_red
emotion_happy            2             2           2
emotion_angry            1             2           1
emotion_sad              1             1           0
```